# BasicTextField maxlength Bug. If you go over the maximum length, BasicTextField doesn't work normally

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

My Code

I tried to limit the length to a maximum of 30 characters,
but if I write more than 30 characters,
it will no longer be entered or erased. Why is that?

What I want to do is create a view that acts like EditText in xml.

The function you want.

- hint
- maxLength

However, the above two functions are not supported in Jetpack Compose TextField().

```
@Composable
fun MyCustomEditText(
    placeholder: String = stringResource(id = "sample"),
) {
    var inputText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    BasicTextField(
        value = inputText,
        onValueChange = {if (it.length <= 30) inputText = it },
        singleLine = false,
        maxLines = 2,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            if (inputText.isEmpty()) { Text(text = placeholder)}
            innerTextField()
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and if I try to enter more than 30 characters, it is prevented. I can also delete characters when 30 have been reached. So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `TextField` or an `OutlinedTextField` to set a placeholder.

Eg :-

```
 TextField(
            value = someText,
            onValueChange = { someText = it },
            label = { Text("Simple TextField") }, // It will be shown on the top when focussed
            placeholder = { Text("Placeholder text") }, // It will be shown as hint when nothing is typed
          )
```

2. you mentioned that you have limited the length by 30 characters and then tried to write more then 30 charac. also in the code I can see a condition where the length is fixed for 30 characters `onValueChange = {if (it.length <= 30) inputText = it }` So I am not sure how you can enter more then 30 char. in this textfield.

Comment: Please look at the code mentioned above.

Comment: Why do you need to set this ? `if (it.length >= 30) {
                inputText = it.substring(0 until 29)
            } else {
                inputText = it
            }`
you can simply use the old one what's the issue with that ?  `onValueChange = {if (it.length <= 30) inputText = it }`

Comment: There are no parameters that can limit the length, so I'm going to customize it and use it.

TextField() or BasicTextField()
* hint
* maxLength

Is there a better idea to set the above conditions?

Comment: for hints you have placeholder and for maxlength you can simply use this :- `onValueChange = {if (it.length <= yourMaxLength) inputText = it }` if the text size is greater `yourMaxLength` then nothing would happen and if you press backspace then the last character would be removed.

Comment: When the maximum length is limited to 30 characters with the code you suggested, the following phenomenon occurs.
Please check the link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRhq6pCS3AWbQacYgtrWPGcDyUL_t34d/view?usp=sharing